# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку у телеграм бота на python, текст с названия кнопки копировался в поле для редактирования сообщения?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, button

Я делаю телеграм бота на питоне, используя либу `pyTelegramBotAPI`.

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, текст с неё (команда), копировалась в поле ввода сообщения

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("/randomize [число №1] [число №2]")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("command2")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Такое сделать навряд ли возможно, попробуй вместо этого сделать с помощью

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(message,имя функции)
```

То есть добавить кнопку с названием Рандомайзер(к примеру), и при ее нажатии будет сообщение от бота для ввода промежутка

Answer (score 0):

Это делается так

```
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def send_welcome(message):
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вставить текст", switch_inline_query_current_chat="#test")
        markup.add(button)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нажмите кнопку, чтобы вставить текст:", reply_markup=markup)
```